# ActiveX Command button to create connection to existing spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel, oledb

I am trying to import reports generated by a 3rd party into a summary spreadsheet.  The reports are generated weekly. So to save time from importing them in manually each week I want to create a button which will create the new tab, create the new connecting, insert the table and rename the table so the summary page can find the new data.

To try to do this first I recorded a Macro and created the connection manually (Data>Existing Connection>Browse for More>Select File> etc.)  Which gave me the following...

```
Application.CutCopyMode = False
With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("yyyy-mm-dd").OLEDBConnection
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .CommandText = Array("Sheet$")
    .CommandType = xlCmdTable
    .Connection = Array( _
    "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Password="""";User ID=Admin;Data Source=C:\folder\yyyy-mm-dd.xls;Mode=Share Deny Write;Extended Properties=""HDR=YES;"";Jet OLEDB:System database="""";Jet OLEDB:" _
    , _
    "Registry Path="""";Jet OLEDB:Database Password="""";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=35;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=0;Jet OLEDB:Global Part" _
    , _
    "ial Bulk Ops=2;Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;Jet OLEDB:New Database Password="""";Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;Je" _
    , _
    "t OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;Jet O" _
    , _
    "LEDB:SFP=False;Jet OLEDB:Support Complex Data=False;Jet OLEDB:Bypass UserInfo Validation=False;Jet OLEDB:Limited DB Caching=Fals" _
    , "e;Jet OLEDB:Bypass ChoiceField Validation=False")
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = True
    .SavePassword = False
    .SourceConnectionFile = ""
    .SourceDataFile = _
    "C:\folder\yyyy-mm-dd.xls"
    .ServerCredentialsMethod = xlCredentialsMethodIntegrated
    .AlwaysUseConnectionFile = False
End With
With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("yyyy-mm-dd")
    .Name = "yyyy-mm-dd"
    .Description = ""
End With
Application.CutCopyMode = False
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array( _
    "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Password="""";User ID=Admin;Data Source=C:\folder\yyyy-mm-dd.xls;Mode=Share Deny Write;Extended Properties=""HDR=YES;"";Jet OLEDB:System database="""";Jet OLEDB:" _
    , _
    "Registry Path="""";Jet OLEDB:Database Password="""";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=35;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=0;Jet OLEDB:Global Part" _
    , _
    "ial Bulk Ops=2;Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;Jet OLEDB:New Database Password="""";Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;Je" _
    , _
    "t OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;Jet O" _
    , _
    "LEDB:SFP=False;Jet OLEDB:Support Complex Data=False;Jet OLEDB:Bypass UserInfo Validation=False;Jet OLEDB:Limited DB Caching=Fals" _
    , "e;Jet OLEDB:Bypass ChoiceField Validation=False"), Destination:=Range( _
    "$A$1")).QueryTable
    .CommandType = xlCmdTable
    .CommandText = Array("Sheet$")
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = True
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .SourceDataFile = _
    "C:\folder\yyyy-mm-dd.xls"
    .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table__2017_10_28"
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

*all of my reports are named after the year-month-day, I have changed the exact dates and file paths above for simplicity*

I then copied this code into the code for my ActiveX Command Button.  This button also has an input box to enter the date of the report you want to input, with a confirmation option.

I then changed everywhere the date appeared from the macro code to use the date inputted from the button.

```
' Input box to add week ending date
Dim WeekEndingDate As String
WeekEndingDate = InputBox("Enter date of week ending", "New Week Tab")
If IsDate(WeekEndingDate) Then
    WeekEndingDate = CDate(WeekEndingDate)

    ' Confirms Date entry, ends code if no is selected
    Dim Ans As VbMsgBoxResult
    Ans = MsgBox("The date you entered for week ending is: " & Format(WeekEndingDate, "Long Date") & ". Are you sure you want to continue?", vbYesNo, "New Week Tab")

    If Ans = vbNo Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

' Ends code if entry is not a date
Else
    MsgBox "This is not a date, try again"
    Exit Sub

End If


'Create new tab to import report on
'To modify code for new year change the folder Ln 43 below to match with new folder
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Select
ActiveSheet.Name = Format(Day(WeekEndingDate), "00") & "-" & MonthName(Month(WeekEndingDate), True) & "-" & Year(WeekEndingDate)


    With ActiveWorkbook.Connections(Year(WeekEndingDate) & "-" & Format(Month(WeekEndingDate), "00") & "-" & Format(Day(WeekEndingDate), "00")).OLEDBConnection
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .CommandText = Array("Sheet$")
    .CommandType = xlCmdTable
    .Connection = Array( _
    "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Password="""";User ID=Admin;Data Source=C:\folder\" & Year(WeekEndingDate) & "-" & Format(Month(WeekEndingDate), "00") & "-" & Format(Day(WeekEndingDate), "00") & ".xls;Mode=Share Deny Write;Extended Properties=""HDR=YES;"";Jet OLEDB:System database="""";Jet OLEDB:" _
    , _
    "Registry Path="""";Jet OLEDB:Database Password="""";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=35;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=0;Jet OLEDB:Global Part" _
    , _
    "ial Bulk Ops=2;Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;Jet OLEDB:New Database Password="""";Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;Je" _
    , _
    "t OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;Jet O" _
    , _
    "LEDB:SFP=False;Jet OLEDB:Support Complex Data=False;Jet OLEDB:Bypass UserInfo Validation=False;Jet OLEDB:Limited DB Caching=Fals" _
    , "e;Jet OLEDB:Bypass ChoiceField Validation=False")
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = True
    .SavePassword = False
    .SourceConnectionFile = ""
    .SourceDataFile = _
    "C:\folder\" & Year(WeekEndingDate) & "-" & Format(Month(WeekEndingDate), "00") & "-" & Format(Day(WeekEndingDate), "00") & ".xls"
    .ServerCredentialsMethod = xlCredentialsMethodIntegrated
    .AlwaysUseConnectionFile = False
End With
With ActiveWorkbook.Connections(Year(WeekEndingDate) & "-" & Format(Month(WeekEndingDate), "00") & "-" & Format(Day(WeekEndingDate), "00"))
    .Name = Year(WeekEndingDate) & "-" & Format(Month(WeekEndingDate), "00") & "-" & Format(Day(WeekEndingDate), "00")
    .Description = ""
End With
Application.CutCopyMode = False
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array( _
    "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Password="""";User ID=Admin;Data Source=C:\folder\" & Year(WeekEndingDate) & "-" & Format(Month(WeekEndingDate), "00") & "-" & Format(Day(WeekEndingDate), "00") & ".xls;Mode=Share Deny Write;Extended Properties=""HDR=YES;"";Jet OLEDB:System database="""";Jet OLEDB:" _
    , _
    "Registry Path="""";Jet OLEDB:Database Password="""";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=35;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=0;Jet OLEDB:Global Part" _
    , _
    "ial Bulk Ops=2;Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;Jet OLEDB:New Database Password="""";Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;Je" _
    , _
    "t OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;Jet O" _
    , _
    "LEDB:SFP=False;Jet OLEDB:Support Complex Data=False;Jet OLEDB:Bypass UserInfo Validation=False;Jet OLEDB:Limited DB Caching=Fals" _
    , "e;Jet OLEDB:Bypass ChoiceField Validation=False"), Destination:=Range( _
    "$A$1")).QueryTable
    .CommandType = xlCmdTable
    .CommandText = Array("Sheet$")
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = True
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .SourceDataFile = _
    "C:\folder\" & Year(WeekEndingDate) & "-" & Format(Month(WeekEndingDate), "00") & "-" & Format(Day(WeekEndingDate), "00") & ".xls"
    .ListObject.DisplayName = "Vehicle_" & Year(WeekEndingDate) & "_" & Format(Month(WeekEndingDate), "00") & "_" & Format(Day(WeekEndingDate), "00")
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

When I try the button I get

> "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range"

on the first line of the copied code from the macro `With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("2017-10-28").OLEDBConnection`

I have tried creating a string with the file name created from the date inputted and I still get the same error.  I have also tried using the code from the macro directly with having the dates used from the input box (even though that would defeat the purpose of my button) and I still get the same error.

I suspect I need to create a connection as an object first, however, I have not been able to figure out how to make this work.

*some additional info: these files will all be on a server, but in the same folder*

Comment: Hey andy, have you tried to see if the connection first exists before connecting to it? if theres only one that should exist you can try using `Connections(1)`

Comment: I'm trying to create the connection, so I don't believe it would exist yet.